# Why does OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter change @Transactional propagation REQUIRES_NEW behavior?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Using Spring 4.3.12, Spring Data JPA 1.11.8 and Hibernate 5.2.12.

We use the `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` to ensure our entity relationships do not throw `LazyInitializationException` after an entity has been loaded. Often in our controllers we use a `@ModelAttribute` annotated method to load an entity by id and make that loaded entity available to a controller's request mapping handler method.

In some cases like auditing we have entity modifications that we want to commit even when some other transaction may error and rollback.  Therefore we annotate our audit work with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` to ensure this transaction will commit successfully regardless of any other (if any) transactions which may or may not complete successfully.

What I've seen in practice using the `OpenEntityManagerInviewFilter`, is that when `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` transactions attempt to commit changes which occurred outside the scope of the new transaction causing work which should always result in successful commits to the database to instead rollback.

#### Example

Given this Spring Data JPA powered repository (the `EmployeeRepository` is similarly defined):

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface MethodAuditRepository extends JpaRepository<MethodAudit,Long> {
}
```

This service:

```
@Service
public class MethodAuditorImpl implements MethodAuditor {
  private final MethodAuditRepository methodAuditRepository;

  public MethodAuditorImpl(MethodAuditRepository methodAuditRepository) {
    this.methodAuditRepository = methodAuditRepository;
  }

  @Override @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void auditMethod(String methodName) {
    MethodAudit audit = new MethodAudit();
    audit.setMethodName(methodName);
    audit.setInvocationTime(LocalDateTime.now());
    methodAuditRepository.save(audit);
  }
}
```

And this controller:

```
@Controller
public class StackOverflowQuestionController {
  private final EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
  private final MethodAuditor methodAuditor;

  public StackOverflowQuestionController(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository, MethodAuditor methodAuditor) {
    this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    this.methodAuditor = methodAuditor;
  }

  @ModelAttribute
  public Employee loadEmployee(@RequestParam Long id) {
    return employeeRepository.findOne(id);
  }

  @GetMapping("/updateEmployee")
  // @Transactional // <-- When uncommented, transactions work as expected (using OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter or not)
  public String updateEmployee(@ModelAttribute Employee employee, RedirectAttributes ra) {
    // method auditor performs work in new transaction
    methodAuditor.auditMethod("updateEmployee"); // <-- at close of this method, employee update occurrs trigging rollback

    // No code after this point executes

    System.out.println(employee.getPin());
    employeeRepository.save(employee);

    return "redirect:/";
  }
}
```

When the `updateEmployee` method is exercised with an invalid pin number `updateEmployee?id=1&pin=12345` (pin number is limited in the database to 4 characters), then no audit is inserted into the database.

Why is this?  Shouldn't the current transaction be suspended when the `MethodAuditor` is invoked?  Why is the modified employee flushing when this `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` transaction commits?

If I wrap the `updateEmployee` method in a transaction by annotating it as `@Transactional`, however, audits will persist as desired.  And this will work as expected whether or not the `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` is used.

Answer (score 0):

While your application (server) tries to make two separate transactions you are still using a single `EntityManager` and single `Datasource` so at any given time JPA and the database see just one transaction. So if you want those things to be separated you need to setup two `Datasource`s and two `EntityManagers`

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  If this is the case, why does annotating the `updateEmployee` method as `@Transaction` resolve the problem? Doesn't a `REQUIRES_NEW` transaction within the same `EntityManager` instance suspend the current transaction allowing the new transaction to run in a way that will not be affected by any other transaction?

Comment: I noticed the NOTE on the [REQUIRES_NEW](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRES_NEW) javadoc: "Actual transaction suspension will not work out-of-the-box on all transaction managers. This in particular applies to JtaTransactionManager, which requires the javax.transaction.TransactionManager to be made available it to it (which is server-specific in standard Java EE)." I'm using [JpaTransactionManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTransactionManager.html)